# Unable to hide Navigation Controller's tool bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a controller (Search Controller) thats embedded inside a navigation controller and a tab bar controller. I then have a container view inside Search Controller that embeds a navigation controller.

For some reason I cannot hide the navigation controller's tool bar that is embedded inside the container view. This is how I am attempting to hide the tool bar.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

No matter, the tool bar at the bottom of my controller will have a tool bar that covers my container view's content. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can hide the toolbar/(tab bar?)? Thanks.

Picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: try doing `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:yes]`

Comment: This will hide my tabBar, which I want. It does seem like I have two tab bars on top of each other though. Ill add a picture of my simulator. @LyricalPanda

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true;
```

Comment: This will hide the tab bar that I want visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what was going wrong or what the proper fix was. But to 'kind of' fix the problem, I simply enlarged the container view underneath my tab bar so that the tab bar I am unable to hide is hidden beneath my universal tab bar.